# Ex Spouse Buy Out Of Home Equity Help!

Tags: united-states, taxes, home-equity, divorce

My husband and I had our divorce finalized 2 months ago. In that decree, he is to pay the mortgage on our house in Kansas, but I need to move. I have been living in the house with my 2 minor children as per the divorce decree. We purchased the house as a married couple and have been married for 6 years.

I do not plan on buying another house right away and will use that money for living expenses such as a vehicle and rent. If I agree to him buying out my equity in the house and I move out, will that money be subject to any kind of tax?

Comment: No, tax there unless its like a half million or something.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE - we really need to know what country this pertains to. Add a comment or tag.

Comment: @PeteB. - $250K profit per person, right? Why not offer a full answer?